# getting String from react-intl's <FormattedNumber>

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I have a FormattedNumber component that looks like this:

```
<FormattedNumber
  style="percent"
  maximumFractionDigits={2}
  value={0.555}
>
</FormattedNumber>
```

And a function that takes a String as an input, I need to pass the FormattedNumber's result to the function, I tried using this to obtain the number:

```
const num = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  <FormattedNumber
  style="percent"
  maximumFractionDigits={2}
  value={0.543}
  >
  </FormattedNumber>
)
```

but it fails with error `Unhandled Rejection (Error): [React Intl] Could not find required intl object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.`

I need a way to convert FormattedNumber to a String, and it has to work with percentages, currency, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to wrap your component into an IntlProvider component.

[Check the React-Intl doc](https://github.com/stripe/react-intl#example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up using `props.intl.formatNumber()` to solve it